# Как перевести с десятичной системы счисления в римскую?

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, с чего начать что б перевести с десятичной системы счисления в римскую и обратно?

Вот собствено 2 метода для примера

```
public static String decimal2Roman(int x) { ... }
public static int roman2Decimal(String s) { ... }
```

Comment: С изучения как устроена римская запись чисел

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас две отдельных задачи. Для решения обоих вам следует ознакомится с  [Римской системой счисления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B).

Первая с переводом с десятичной системы - это задача на применения [оператора деления с остатком (%)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17). Алгоритм действий примерно следующий:

1. Смотрим разрядность числа. (Допустим число на входе программы 23, тор разрядность такого числа 2)
2. Берем минимальный делитель для числа с разрядностью из пункта 1. (Смотрим таблицу римских цифр, для разрядности 2, у нас есть два римским числа X - 10,L - 50. Берем меньшее 10)
3. Делим входное число нацело 23 / 10 = 2
4. Записываем результат вычисления как Римское число в строку(2 раза по X, получится XX)
5. Делим входное число с остатком 23 % 2 = 3
6. Если разрядность результата деления с остатком больше 2 переходим в пункт 1, иначе в пункт 7
7. Берем остаток от деления и находим ему соответствие в Римской системе счисления 3 -> III
   8 Добавляем результат вычисления как Римское число в конец строки (XX + III = XXIII)
   .

Вторая задача более интересная - это задача парсинга строки. Вам нужно будет находить соответствующим символам из строки соответствие в десятичной системе.
 т.к. в римской системе счисления нельзя писать более 3 одинаковых символов подряд(IV а не IIII, XL а не XXXX), то вам придется находить соответствие не одному символу а сразу двум.

В результате у вас получиться массив символов, например для римского числа XXXIV, у вас должен получится массив [10,10,10,4]. Суммируя элементы массива вы найдете нужное вам число, в примере это будет 34.

Для проверки можете использовать [калькулятор онлайн.](https://planetcalc.ru/378/)

Answer (score 1):

Большинство задач уже были решены до тебя. Если ты не учишься, то, обычно, не стоит переизобретать велосипед. Вот ссылки на решения с тестами (прошу прощение за столь короткий ответ):

1. [Из римских в арабские](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Roman_numerals/Decode#Java_2)
2. [Из арабских в римские](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Roman_numerals/Encode#Java)

PS: на сайте с указанными ссылками есть тысячи других решенных относительно несложных задач для большиства языков программирования.