# Перевод числа из римской системы счисления в десятичное представление

Tags: powershell, числа, системы-счисления

Пытаюсь реализовать конвертер чисел из римской системы счисления, встречающихся по тексту, в десятичное представление. В чем затык? IIL не является валидным числом, например. Как такие числа отсеивать? И второе. Число вида IX, как их корректно обрабатывать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как перевести с десятичной системы счисления в римскую?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1075185/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e)

Comment: А почему же на powershell? Вот пример на С++ https://medium.com/@sravyadivakarla/roman-to-integer-c-c94dad7d6eed

Answer (score 0):

В `PowerShell` проверку корректности значений можно осуществлять непосредственно при объявлении (описании) параметров функции. Иными словами:

```
#requires -version 6
function ConvertFrom-Roman {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    # параметр обязателен и может передаваться через пайп
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    # паттерн валидации допустимых значений
    [ValidatePattern('^(?=[MDCLXVI])M*(C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(I[XV]|V?I{0,3})$')]
    # значение не может быть пустым
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    # тип значения - строка
    [String]$Number
  )

  process {
    # карта римских чисел
    $map = @{I = 1; V = 5; X = 10; L = 50; C = 100; D = 500; M = 1000}
    for ($i, $a = 0, [Char[]]$Number; $i -lt $a.Length; $i++) { # разбираем посимвольно
      ${<}, ${>} = "$($a[$i])", "$($a[$i + 1])" # текущий и следующий символы
      $dec += [Int64]"$('+-'[$i + 1 -lt $a.Length -and $map[${<}] -lt $map[${>}]])$($map[${<}])"
    }
    $dec # результат
  }
}
```

Примеры использования.

```
ConvertFrom-Roman XLVII # 47
'dlxxvii' | ConvertFrom-Roman # 577
('mmxx', 'cdxxix', 'di').ForEach{ConvertFrom-Roman $_} # 2020, 429, 501
```